# Can pidgin + OTR be used the same way as cryptocat? chat without specify server?

Tags: pidgin, instant-messaging, chat

Cryptocat is a messenger for the browser giving the user an end-to-end encrypted messenging service. A room can be created and shared before getting into contact, another user can be verified by asking a question giving a preshared answer.

Question:
Is the same possible with pidgin+OTR too? I am specifically referring to creating a room for only two users, without having the need to specify a server.

Comment: Couldn't you just use the preshared answer in an indentical way?  You both contact each other ahead of time, shared the answer with one another, then any messenger that supports off the record messaging can be used.  I can't tell if your asking if Pidgin has the concept of these rooms  or not.

Comment: pidgin can do rooms, but I always have to specify a server. Not so in cryptocat, no server specified.

Comment: Pidgin requires you connect to a server which supports a messenging protocol which it supports.  So are you asking if Pidgin supports Cryptocat protocol because it would have to in order to provide the type of functionality your asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Pidgin uses protocol plugins, so in theory you could find/write a plugin to emulate this "serverless" behavior (but its worth noting that there is almost certainly a server involved *somewhere*, even if it is implied).